# How to ripple on a sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, ripple

I'm trying to implement a program that turns a cube into a sphere based on key presses, and ripples whenever it's clicked. I managed to implement the cube-to-sphere-and-back part, but I have completely no idea where to start on the rippling. I've looked at tons of sources online, I get the math, but I have no idea how to implement it on my vertex shader. Can anyone help me with my dilemma? Thank you!

Here's my cpp, vsh, and fsh: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4hkcF9foOTgbUozMjZmSHJhQWM/view?usp=sharing

I'm using GLSL, OpenGL 4.4.0

Here's my code for the vertex shader:

```
    #version 120

    attribute vec3 pos;
    varying vec4 out_color;
    uniform float t;
    float PI = 3.14159265357;

    int factor = 2; //for determining colors
    int num_colors; // = factor * 3 (because RGB)
    float currang = 0;
    float angfac;

    vec4 calculate( float a )
    {
        //this is just to calculate for the color
    }

    void main() {
        num_colors = factor*3;
        angfac = 2*PI/num_colors;

        float ang = atan( pos.z, pos.x )+PI; 
        out_color = calculate(ang);

        //rotation
        mat3 rotateX = mat3(
        vec3( 1,         0,        0),
        vec3( 0,    cos(t),   sin(t)),
        vec3( 0,   -sin(t),   cos(t))
        );

        mat3 rotateY = mat3(
        vec3( cos(t),    0,   -sin(t)),
        vec3( 0,         1,         0),
        vec3( sin(t),    0,    cos(t))
        );

        mat3 rotateZ = mat3(
        vec3( cos(t),    sin(t),       0),
        vec3(-sin(t),    cos(t),       0),
        vec3(      0,         0,  cos(t))
        );

        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4((pos.xyz*rotateY*rotateX) , 1.0 );
    }
```

and here's parts of my cpp file:

```
//usual include statements

using namespace std;

enum { ATTRIB_POS };
GLuint mainProgram = 0;

// I use this to indicate the position of the vertices
struct Vtx {
    GLfloat x, y, z;
};

const GLfloat PI = 3.14159265357;

const int sideLength = 10;
const size_t nVertices = (sideLength*sideLength*sideLength)-((sideLength-2)*(sideLength-2)*(sideLength-2));

Vtx cube[nVertices];
Vtx sphere[nVertices];
Vtx diff[nVertices];

const double TIME_SPEED = 0.01;

int mI = 4*(sideLength-1);
const int sLCubed = sideLength*sideLength*sideLength;
int indices[nVertices*nVertices];

GLfloat originX = 0.0f; //offset
GLfloat originY = 0.0f; //offset

bool loadShaderSource(GLuint shader, const char *path) {...}

void checkShaderStatus(GLuint shader) {...}

bool initShader() {...}

//in this part of the code, I instantiate an array of indices to be used by glDrawElements()

void transform(int fac)
{
    //move from cube to sphere and back by adding/subtracting values and updating cube[].xyz
    //moveSpeed = diff[]/speedFac
    //fac is to determine direction (going to sphere or going to cube; going to sphere is plus, going back to cube is minus)
    for( int i = 0; i<nVertices; i++ )
    {
        cube[i].x += fac*diff[i].x;
        cube[i].y += fac*diff[i].y;
        cube[i].z += fac*diff[i].z;
    }
}

void initCube() {...} //computation for the vertices of the cube depending on sideLength

void initSphere() {...} //computation for the vertices of the sphere based on the vertices of the cube

void toSphere() {...} //changes the values of the array of vertices of the cube to those of the sphere

void initDiff() {...} //computes for the difference of the values of the vertices of the sphere and the vertices of the cube for the slow transformation

int main() {
    //error checking (GLEW, OpenGL versions, etc)

    glfwSetWindowTitle("CS177 Final Project");
    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    if ( !initShader() ) {
        return -1;
    }

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POS);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vtx), cube);

    initCube();
    initIndices();
    initSphere();
    initDiff();

    glUseProgram(mainProgram);
    GLuint UNIF_T = glGetUniformLocation(mainProgram, "t");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    float t = 0;
    glUniform1f(UNIF_T, t);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glPointSize(2.0);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES,16);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    do {
        int width, height;
        glfwGetWindowSize( &width, &height );
        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        t += TIME_SPEED;
        glUniform1f(UNIF_T, t);

        if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_DEL)) transform(-1);
        if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_INSERT)) transform( 1 );
        if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_HOME)) initCube();
        if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_END)) toSphere();

        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, nVertices*nVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

        glfwSwapBuffers();
    } while ( glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) );

    glDeleteProgram(mainProgram);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you wish to apply ripples on a flat surface like a pool or a puddle, you make the displacements along the surface normal of the target object. In the case of a body of water, we assume that the surface is flat and under the influence of gravity. This means that we use the Y axis. A displacement of 1 unit would entail moving the vertex by 1 unit in the positive Y direction. Now, if we then have a sphere, the surface normal is different at each point on the sphere. However the concept is unchanged - displace along the surface normal.

Comment: Please just post the code parts (only the relevant ones!) in the question. The google drive does not work for me, and it is not going to stay around either.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you for your answer! I get the entire concept, from normalization to all the equations and the math and all that (maybe not all, but at least most of it), but I just don't know how to translate that into code.

Comment: @starmole oh, alright! I'll edit post my vertex shader code, since that's the important part, I think?

Comment: Hi all. I already solved the problem regarding rippling. Now I need to work on antialiasing and click detection. Thank you so much!